# How to remove leading zeros from the calculator expression in a string? python

Tags: python, string, strsplit, leading-zero

I have a doubt, in python
the string is, `Z = "00123+0567*29/03-7"`

how to convert it to "123+567*29/3-7"

Even I tried with `re.split('[+]|[*]|-|/', Z)` later with `for i in res : i = i.lstrip("0")`
but it will split correctly, but to join back with the same operands as in the string "Z" as `Z = "123+567*29/3-7"`

How to resolve it

Comment: If you have a list of strings, you can combine them back into a single string using `''.join(strings)`.

Comment: @FrankYellin But what about the operands?

Comment: What's your question?  You take your string, you break it into pieces, you strip each piece, and then you join then back together as a string.  Isn't that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @FrankYellin What i meant was i expect the result to be "123+567*29/3-7"

Comment: Isn't that what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cut_zeroes(Z):
    i, res = 0, []
    n = len(Z)

    while i < n:
        j = i
        while i < n and Z[i] not in '+-/*':
            i += 1
        res.append(int(Z[j:i]))

        if i < n:
            res.append(Z[i])

        i += 1

    return ''.join(map(str,res))
  

Z = "00123+0567*29/03-700"
print(cut_zeroes(Z))
```

Comment: instead of  `int` we could use the `float`  in `res.append(int(Z[j:i]))` in since we need to consider the decimal values @Andrey

Comment: @KaryKathews yes, you are correct, in case the numbers can be real, it is necessary to use float so as not to lose the decimal part. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

```
Z = "00123+0567*29/03-7"
print Z

import re
res = re.split(r'(\D)', Z)
print res

empty_lst = []
for i in res :
    i = i.lstrip("0")
    empty_lst.append(i)
    print i
print empty_lst
new_str = ''.join(empty_lst)
print new_str
```

Comment: Thank you so much @VinayKurmi

Comment: we need to cinsider the decimal values

Answer (score 1):

```py
def zero_simplify(Z):
    from re import sub
    return [char for char in sub("0{2,}", "0", Z)]

Z = "00123+0567*29/03-7+0-000"
Z = zero_simplify(Z)
pos = len(Z)-1
while pos>-1:
    if Z[pos]=="0":
        end = pos
        while Z[pos] == "0":
            pos-=1
            if pos==-1:
                del Z[pos+1:end+1]
        if (not Z[pos].isdigit()) and (Z[pos] != ".") and (Z[pos] == "0"):
            del Z[pos+1:end+1]
    else:
        pos-=1
Z = "".join(Z)
print(Z)
```

What this does is set `Z`, 'listify' it, and set `pos` to the last position in `Z`.  Then it removes all of the unnecessary `0`s using the loop and `Z = "".join(Z)`.  Then it `print`s `Z` at the end.  If you want a function to remove the zeroes, you can have it this way:

```py
def zero_simplify(Z):
    from re import sub
    return [char for char in sub("0{2,}", "0", Z)]

def remove_unnecessary_zeroes(Z):
    Z = [char for char in Z]
    pos = len(Z)-1
    while pos>-1:
        if Z[pos]=="0":
            end = pos
            while Z[pos] == "0":
                pos-=1
                if pos==-1:
                    del Z[pos+1:end+1]
            if (not Z[pos].isdigit()) and (Z[pos] != ".") and (Z[pos] == "0"):
                del Z[pos+1:end+1]
        else:
            pos-=1
    Z = "".join(Z)
    return Z
Z = "00123+0567*29/03-7+0-000"
print(remove_unnecessary_zeroes(Z))
```

Try it yourself and tell me in the comments if it worked for you!

Comment: One more thing, we need to consider the decimal values

Comment: @KaryKathews : Thank you I have now added support for decimal support

Comment: but if we use "00123+0567*29/03-7+0-0" i get "34-4+9**2.1+-" can you suggest how we can make "34-4+9**2.1+0-0"? @Lakshya Raj

Comment: @KaryKathews: OK I updated my code to be careful about numbers made of zeros!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise *(if you strip all the comment in the code)* and elegant way to achieve this:

```
import re

Z = "00123+0567*29/03-7"

operators = re.findall('\D', Z)               # List all the operators used in the string
nums = re.split('\D', Z)                      # List all the numbers in the list

operators.append('')                          # Add an empty operator at the end
nums = [num.lstrip('0') for num in nums]      # Strip all the leading zeroes from each numbers

# Create a list with the operands (numbers) concatenated by operators

num_operator_list = [nums[i] + operators[i] for i in range(len(nums))]

# Join all the intermediate expressions to create a final expression

final_expression = ''.join(num_operator_list)
print(final_expression)
```

#### Output

`123+567*29/3-7`

#### Explanation

First of all you need to separate the operators and the operands and then `lstrip` the zeroes from each operands. After this **add an additional empty operator** at the end of operator list. Then concatenate each operand with corresponding operator (the empty operator is concatenated with the last operand). Finally, join the list to get a final expression.

Comment: @KaryKathews I have fixed the issue. You can try this again...

Comment: but what about the values that have decimal?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with regular expressions:

```
import re
Z = "00123+0567*29/03-7"
r1=r"(\D)0+(\d+)"
r2=r"\b0+(\d+)"
#substitute non-digit,leading zeroes, digits with non-digit and digits
sub1=re.sub(r1,r"\1\2",Z)
#substitute start of string, leading zeroes, digits with digits
sub2=re.sub(r2,r"\1",sub1)
print(sub2)
```

It is done in two passes (to handle the leading zeroes in the beginning of the string), I don't know if it's possible to do in one pass.